# Fiddler for Notes Xpages

Tags: proxy, xpages, lotus-notes, fiddler, xpinc

I want to use Fiddler for my new Notes Xpages application. My application sends mail automatically and in this email there is a link which opens the document in the application in Notes. I want to see what's going on when I click on this link with Fiddler. Can anyone say what I have to do to get this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to File->Preferences...->Location->edit actual location

change proxy-configuration to '127.0.0.1:8888'

copy first your actual location and then make this changes so you can switch fast between them